# How can I generate ensembles from spatially correlated PDFs?

Tags: correlation, spatial, ensemble-learning

So I have a grid where every grid point has PDF of a variable (precipitation). The PDFs are spatially correlated.

What is the best way for generating ensembles that are spatially and temporally realistic? I am just looking for ideas to read further and explore. Maybe there are ideas outside my field I am not aware of.

Comment: A good set of keywords to search is "spatial conditional simulation."  Include something like "spatio-temporal" to focus on space-time models. It's getting to be a big field; it's active; techniques get complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I'll search. If you know more resources, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the PDFs parametrised, and do they all share the same parameterisation?

If so, you could look at the co-variance matrix of the parameters between the various samples. By diagonalising the cov matrix and applying the same transformation to your original parameters, I think you can then work in a space where all the parameters are independent - so you can simply choose a configuration by independently choosing the parameters at random (from the correct distribution for the new variable). Once you've got a random state, you can then untransform the state to get a new state that captures the various couplings between the samples.

Someone else might be able to give you a more technically correct version of that :)

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by parameter here? I basically have mu, sigma values etc.

Comment: Yeah, those are what I mean by parameters :)

Comment: I have to admit the method you are describing is a bit dense for me right now. Any readings or code I can read?

Comment: I would love to know more about this method that you described,

Comment: Hmm, I can't remember exactly where I read this. www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/ has something similar... I'll let you know if I find my original source.

Comment: This approach is a nice idea (+1), but it works only for multigaussian stochastic fields, which are determined by the means and covariances and remain multigaussian under such linear transformations. It can be extended to some other distributions using a generalized linear modeling approach described in Diggle and Ribeiro Jr., *Model-Based Geostatistics.* For spatio-temporal fields at any reasonable resolution the calculations are burdensome or impossible, so alternative methods are typically used.

Comment: Good knowledge! I doff my cap to thee :0)

Comment: @whuber Can you please talk more about the alternative methods?